# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm using a very simple code and fetching data from firestore

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        ....
    });
    
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
    
export default db;
```

but i keep getting this error

```
[2021-06-05T00:58:41.274Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.6.5): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times.
Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]:
 Permission denied on resource project.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

1. i do have a very fast internet connection
2. my clock is also synced with the standard time

Now, i have no clue why is this happening?

please someone help me out!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your environment is pointing to the real firestone database and not the Firestore Emulator. When I came across this same issue, that was the reason.

I'm using an Angular framework so I had to comment out those environment references in my app.module.ts file.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, InformUserComponent],
  entryComponents: [InformUserComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the app is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    }),

  ],
  providers: [AuthService, { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    // {
    //   provide: USE_FIRESTORE_EMULATOR, useValue: environment.useEmulators ?
    //     ['localhost', 8080] : undefined
    // },
    // {
    //   provide: USE_FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR, useValue: environment.useEmulators ?
    //     ['localhost', 5001] : undefined
    // },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue. The connection was working on some environments, but on my client's corporate network it wasn't.

After a loong research on the internet, I found [an issue on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674) talking about it.

Here's what worked for me:

```
const firestoreDB = initializeFirestore(firebaseApp, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true, // this line
  useFetchStreams: false, // and this line
})
```

Here i'm using firebase v9. For firebase v8 it's something like:

```
firebase().firestore().settings({
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true, // this line
  useFetchStreams: false, // and this line
})
```

Answer (score 4):

i was able to resolve this issue by using my credential directly where i initializeApp my firebase config, i was previously calling them from my env file i think my app was not getting the env before

Comment: Thanks man! My issue is resolved albeit temporarily. Cannot believe such a thing could cause such a headache. I swear it was working yesterday when I migrated the credentials to .env.

Comment: Had the same issue when using quasar. It was resolved when i moved the firebase config variables from the .env and used them directly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and tried to use the @atunde arisekola approach. If you can solve this problem by using direct credentials in your `firebaseConfig` variable, consider to check whether your `.env.local` or any other `.env` you are using is located in the root directory. In my case had `firebaseConfig.ts` and `.env.local` in the same directory, and thus the error occured. It is recommended to have`.env` in the root of your App.

Answer (score 1):

### For people using Next 13 with Firestore 9:

If you use ServerComponents (default components in Next 13) and you also use `.env.local` to set your Firebase env vars, then everything should work no matter what you call your env vars.

BUT most likely you want to turn components related to Firestore data fetching (esp. real-time onSnapshot) to ClientComponent by writing `'use client'` at the top of the file, so you have access to states. In this case, you have to remember to add `NEXT_PUBLIC_` before every env var (e.g. `NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY`). This will expose the env vars to the browser (i.e. client).

Also, make sure you don't have any typos in env var names.

#### Links:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components
- https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue as well with angular fire.
What I have changed is to add firestore settings to the provider of app module:

According to the GitHub [issues](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674) discussion, I think you can try `experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling` first.
And option `useFetchStreams` is unnecessary except for users who are using very old browser versions.

```
import { SETTINGS as FIRESTORE_SETTINGS } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


providers:[
    {
      provide: FIRESTORE_SETTINGS,
      useValue: { experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true, merge: true },
    }
]
```

and you can use [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org) to reproduce the firebase errors.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue because I forgot to expose those configs to the browser. With that, if you're using Next.js for ex. and defining those in `.env`, you must add the `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix. Otherwise, you'll see the same error.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser