# Cloud firestore collection not showing up in cloud firestore's database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XTRElVAZ9Y&t=1468s for google drive clone. At 24:00, he created a database in cloud firestore and when he added the folder, it showed up in the cloud firestore. I also did the same but the collection was not reflected in the database. Authentication and data of new registered users is working fine in firebase. But when I try to add a collection, it does not show up.

This is the firebase.js file.

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
});

const firestore = app.firestore();
export const database = {
folders: firestore.collection("folders"),
files: firestore.collection("files")
};
export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
```

This is the file where the adding of folder takes place AddFolder.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faFolderPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { database } from "../../firebase";
import { useAuth } from "../../context/AuthContext";

export default function AddFolderButton({ currentFolder }) {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const { currentUser } = useAuth();

function openModal() {
setOpen(true);
}

function closeModal() {
setOpen(false);
}
//                     This is the function where collection is added to firebase
function handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
//           Below is the add part. I also tried to make it await database.folders.add({...})
database.folders           
  .add({
    name: name
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(
      "There was an error uploading a file to Cloud Storage:",
      error
    );
  });
setName("");
closeModal();
}

return (
 <>
  <Button onClick={openModal} variant="outline-success" size="sm">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFolderPlus} />
  </Button>
  <Modal show={open} onHide={closeModal}>
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Modal.Body>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Folder Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            required
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={closeModal}>
          Close
        </Button>
        <Button variant="success" type="submit">
          Add Folder
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Form>
   </Modal>
  </>
 );
 }
```

The collection is not getting added to the cloud firestore.I tried creating a new project in firebase and also used the new credentials of the new project in .env file. But this didnt work. When i tried to await the handleSubmit() function's database.folder.add(....) part and console logged something after the add part, nothing was logged. It took a long time after add part was trigger and nothing was logged when async and await were used.

Then I cloned the youtuber's repository from github and tried to work with his completed project after adding credentials in .env file but it didnt work either. Please help resolved this issue.

Since I am using CodesandboxIO, anyone who was to see the project I am doing can visit using https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-leaf-twc2r?file=/src/components/google-drive/

EDIT 1 :
This is the schema of firestore.
[Image Link of Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7eMC.jpg)

This is the code I am using for getting collection from firestore

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection("folders")
      .get()
      .then((snapshots) => {
        snapshots.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc);
        });
      });
    setName("");
    closeModal();
  }
```

I tried to turn off firewall in my PC. But when i click the button to get for the 1st time, it shows the Permission denied error mentioned in my 1st comment and when I click again, it gives an empty array. I have checked the rules in firestore, I had already set them to always true.

Answer (score 0):

Creating Collections Firestore is not always reflected immediately especially on empty databases, this is only a UI quirk that a page refresh fixes.

The real key is can you read the data after pushing it to your Firebase projects as it's quite common for new users to be looking in the wrong project or even the wrong database. you can test this with a  `.get()` method on the same reference.

I would also create console.log's in each step to ensure your functions are being executed correctly and effectively, as running async tasks inside a sync block is not blocking and can prematurely end the function before being caught.

There is also the potential of binding issues as I see you have `function` declarations and in some instances, this can detach from the firebase scope, ensure that you are using arrow functions to reduce this issue.

Comment: thanks for the replyy. so i tried to perform the get function after adding a dummy folder collection in the firestore manually. in the inspect element, i got the error mention in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845455/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-connection-failed-1-times post.  

 Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]:
 Permission denied on resource project. 

now i am unable to find a solution to this online

Comment: have you tried another pc? sounds like it could be blocked by something like a firewall
I would also suggest testing a minimal project, a basic single-page web example.

Comment: Hi. I tried to turn off firewall in my PC. But when i click the button to get for the 1st time, it shows the Permission denied error mentioned above and when I click again, it gives an empty array. I have checked the rules in firestore, I had already set them to always true. I have updated the question showing now the schema in firestore and the part where I am writing the get() method

Comment: that should be `snapshots.forEach()` since it's a query snapshot