# Firestore not connected using Expo-dev-client

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

If I use `expo start`, my firestore work fine in Expo Go. But when i use `expo start --dev-client` it stop working. I already tried using EAS using [EAS Migration Guide](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/migrate-to-eas-update/), but the same error happen.

 Here is the Error message:

```
@firebase/firestore:, Firestore (8.2.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
    at node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/index.cjs.js:98:8 in defaultLogHandler
    at node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/index.cjs.js:212:8 in Logger.prototype.error
    at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/rn/prebuilt.rn-f9cd27ba.js:60:8 in P
    at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/rn/prebuilt.rn-f9cd27ba.js:8135:20 in <global>
    at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/rn/prebuilt.rn-f9cd27ba.js:8105:8 in stream.onMessage$argument_0
    at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/rn/prebuilt.rn-f9cd27ba.js:5218:67 in Ds#constructor
    at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/rn/prebuilt.rn-f9cd27ba.js:11781:54 in <global>
    
      @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (8.2.2): Connection, WebChannel transport errored
```

There is no problem with my connection, because the API in the App is still working.

 is there an additional setting for EAS or expo-dev-client?

Here is how i start my firebase

```
class FirebaseServices {
static handleFirebaseConfig() {
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: 'API_KEY',
        authDomain: "firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
        storageBucket: "STORAGE",
        messagingSenderId: "ID",
        appId: "APP_ID",
        measurementId: "ID"
    };
    let app;
    if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
        app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    }
    else {
        app = firebase.app();
    }
    return app;    
}}    const db = FirebaseServices.handleFirebaseConfig().firestore()
```

Comment: Could you please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on your question. Also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845455/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-connection-failed-1-times) and see if it helps.

Comment: Thx @MarcAnthonyB, adding experimentalForceLongPolling to firestore setting solve my issue!

Comment: @muhammadripqi Please post an answer mentioning what solved your issue so that anyone visiting this question later, will get to have an answer right away than going through each comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve this using the answer from the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845455/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-connection-failed-1-times), by adding experimentalForceLongPolling.

```
 class FirebaseServices {
static handleFirebaseConfig() {
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: 'API_KEY',
        authDomain: "firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
        storageBucket: "STORAGE",
        messagingSenderId: "ID",
        appId: "APP_ID",
        measurementId: "ID"
    };
    let app;
    if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
        app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
        firebase().firestore().settings({
          experimentalForceLongPolling: true, // this line
          useFetchStreams: false, // and this line
        })
    }
    else {
        app = firebase.app();
    }
    return app;    
    }
   }  
  const db = FirebaseServices.handleFirebaseConfig().firestore()
```

And i already upgrade my firebase to v9, so it change to something like this

```
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

   const firestoreDB = initializeFirestore(app, {
     experimentalForceLongPolling: true,  
     useFetchStreams: false,  
    })
   export const dbFs = getFirestore(app);
```