# React-Vite app deployed in vercel consoles in browser this error: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, vercel

I am using firebase for authetication, storage and Firestore Database in a react-vite app that is deployed in vercel.

I am getting the error :

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.8.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

When I try to open the app in a browser( I don't get it every time but most of the times especially on mobiles or tablets).

Here is the firebase.js file that I have in my project to configure the firestore.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getAuth,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  FacebookAuthProvider,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getPerformance } from 'firebase/performance';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const perf = getPerformance(app);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);


// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
export const auth = getAuth(app);

// Create a GoogleAuthProvider instance
export const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

// Create a AppleAuthProvider instance
export const facebookProvider = new FacebookAuthProvider();

export default app;
```

1. The environmental variables are all set correct in the .env file I have triple checked them.
2. Also the internet connection is healthy, I have tried it in many devices and different internet connections.

The rules that i have on the cloud firestore are:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      // Allow read access to everyone
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The version of firebase i use is 10.4.0 and this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "***",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run dev\" \"npm run server\"",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.11.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^10.4.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "first-input-delay": "^0.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vite-plugin-env-compatible": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried all the solutions that i found on the internet about the issue.

Such as:

- using many wifi or ethernet connections and devices
- experimentalForceLongPolling
- Please visit https://debug-my.firebaseapp.com/ and check the results at the end. If the tests "with default options" fail (or are very slow) but the "with forceLongPolling" ones succeed, then this indicates your traffic is likely going through a proxy that is buffering responses in a way that is not compatible with Firestore. And those are the results :

```
All tests done.
1: webchannel.googleapis.com with default options: SUCCEEDED (1956ms)
2: webchannel.googleapis.com with detectBufferingProxy: SUCCEEDED (1737ms)
3: webchannel.googleapis.com with forceLongPolling: SUCCEEDED (2160ms)
4: webchannel.sandbox.google.com with default options: SUCCEEDED (2070ms)
5: webchannel.sandbox.google.com with detectBufferingProxy: SUCCEEDED (1710ms)
6: webchannel.sandbox.google.com with forceLongPolling: SUCCEEDED (1717ms)
7: Firestore listen test with default options: SUCCEEDED (1520ms)
8: Firestore listen test with detectBufferingProxy: SUCCEEDED (1356ms)
9: Firestore listen test with forceLongPolling: SUCCEEDED (1090ms)
```

Comment: please try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845455/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-connection-failed-1-times)  and let us know .